# Simplest way of writing "while not the initial value"

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic, cycle

If you want to do something while a variable foo != 5, having initial value 5 (for example)  .

**Does anyone know a cleaner way of doing this?**
One way is:

```
def try1():
    foo = 5
    aux = False
    while (foo != 5) or (aux == False):
        aux = True
        foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
        print(foo)
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear why you would want to execute the loop at least once if the initial value is already an acceptable value for later iterations. The only difference between this loop and `while foo != 5` is that it advances the random number generator by at least one value.

Comment: I don't think it matters, but if you are curious imagine having a network of 5 nodes, you want to stop the cycle when you find a path that reaches the first node again. e.g. 1-4-2-3-1 end cycle.
The example I gave was merely illustrative to avoid adding more code

Comment: OK, in that case you would probably want to be *accumulating* values of `foo` in a list, not just printing them. `foo = [5]`.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm doing in my code, I literally wrote this code just to show the example for the problem I asked. The real code is larger and more confusing

Comment: In this case, you (inadvertently) simplified too much; you got rid of the reason for needing to repeat the loop at least once :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a repeat-until structure, there isn't one in Python.  But, you can get something similar by creating an iterator. You can then use that iterator in a `for _ in ...` statement to obtain the desired behaviour.

```
  def repeatUntil(condition):
      yield
      while not condition(): yield

  foo = 5
  for _ in repeatUntil(lambda:foo==5):
     foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
     print(foo)
```

Or repeatWhile() if you want to express the continuation condition instead of the stop condition.  (in both cases, the condition will be tested at the end of the loop)

```
  def repeatWhile(condition):
      yield
      while condition(): yield

  foo = 5
  for _ in repeatWhile(lambda:foo!=5):
     foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
     print(foo)
```

Note that this approach will provide proper processing of `continue` where as `while True: ... if foo==5: break` would require extra code (and extra care).

For example:

```
foo = 5
while True:
    foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
    if someCondition == True: continue # loop will not stop even if foo == 5
    print(foo)
    if foo == 5: break
```

**[UPDATE]** If you prefer using a while statement and don't want to have `lambda:` in the way, you could create a `loopUntilTrue()` function to manage forcing the first pass generically:

```
def loopUntilTrue():  # used in while not loop(...):
    firstTime = [True]
    def loop(condition):
        return (not firstTime or firstTime.clear()) and condition
    return loop

foo = 5
reached = loopUntilTrue()
while not reached(foo==5):    
    foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
    print(foo)
```

*Note that you need to initialize a new instance of `loopUntilTrue()` for each while statement.  This also implies that you will have to use different variable names (for `reached`) in nested while loops that use this approach*

You can do the same thing with an exit condition:

```
def loopUntilFalse(): # used in while loop(...):
    firstTime = [True]
    def loop(condition):
        return (firstTime and not firstTime.clear()) or condition
    return loop

foo = 5
outcome = loopUntilFalse()
while outcome(foo!=5):    
    foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
    print(foo)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "proper processing of continue", and why wouldn't the other approach do that?

Comment: If you have `while True` and `if foo==5:break` at the last line of the instruction block, using `continue` anywhere in these instructions would not execute the last line and so would not properly stop the while loop (potentially causing an infinite loop)

Answer (score 3):

Use an infinite loop that explicitly breaks if the condition is true at the *end* of the body.

```
def try1():
    foo = 5
    while True:
        foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
        print(foo)
        if foo == 5:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Another clean way to do this, is to evaluate the statement once before the loop.

```
def try1():
    foo = 5

    foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
    print(foo)

    while foo != 5:
        foo = (random.randint(1,100) // (foo +1)) +1
        print(foo)
```

This way, foo is generated once, then the loop is entered.